# Ударение в слове "полиграфия"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Так как же верно: полиграфИя, или полигрАфия. Допустимо ли применять оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Раньше вариант полиграфИя признавался единственно верным. Сейчас некоторые словари (Лопатин, в частности) дают эти варианты как равноправные.